# NSUndoManager and runModalForWindow:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a simple Core Data app which displays a list of entities in the main window. To create or add new entities, I use a second modal window with a separate managed object context so changes can be undone/redone without interfering with the main managed object context.

The editing window is launched using `runModalForWindow:`. If I make a series of discrete changes in this modal window, doing a single undo results in undoing ALL my changes. I tried setting the run loop modes of `NSUndoManager` (obtained from the second managed object context) to contain `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode` but that didn't appear to make any difference.

If I don't launch the window using `runModalForWindow:` and simply use `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`, everything works as expected.

Has anyone run into this before?

Kevin

Comment: I'm unclear why you want two contexts. Do you want two undo stacks? When you write "a single undo..." which stack are you undoing, the original or the modal window's context?

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using the Cocoa Application Kit for your application? Not sure why it wouldn't do that on your main window, and only on the overlay.. but this might be in the right direction..

The following quote is from the [Mac Dev Center, NSUndoManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When performing undo an NSUndoManager
>   saves the operations reverted so that
>   you can redo the undos. If used in a
>   Cocoa Application Kit-based
>   application, NSUndoManager groups all
>   operations within a single cycle of
>   the run loop, so that performing an
>   undo reverts all changes that occurred
>   during the cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm performing several actions independantly on the second modal window. As such, each event is being handled in a different cycle of the run loop. As I mentioned in the original post, it works fine if I use makeKeyAndOrderFront:.